# How to write SQL query to show the workers in a descending order of who has worked the most in the current payroll

Tags: mysql

Somewhere in the Admin Control Panel ~ Employees section, I have a page called EmployeeStatics, where I aim to show the worker who worked the highest amount of time until now in the current payroll, the worker who worked the less amount of time till now, the highest paid the lowest paid etc etc.

I tried this query, but it only gives me the sum of all employees:

```
SELECT SUM(totalTime) as sumTotal from payroll_details WHERE payroll_id = ?
```

Comment: Okay let me cut it short ,I maybe understand the term of subqueries wrong, I will put a bigger part of the code in the question and give more information. Give me a moment.

Comment: Ok, so your question boils down to "How to write SQL query to show the workers in a descending order of who has worked the most in the current payroll". Then your question has nothing to do with PHP or mysqli. You can edit the question by removing PHP code and leaving only the SQL you tried. Also, you need to show us your schema design. BTW I have no idea what `SELECT MAX(SUM(totalTime))` was meant to do. This makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the full list of total time in descending order, then you don't need the `MAX(SUM())`. Just

```
SELECT SUM(totaltime) as total_sum 
   FROM payroll_details  
   GROUP BY payroll_id  
   ORDER BY total_sum DESC
```

You can add `LIMIT 1` to show only the top user or `ASC LIMIT 1` to show the bottom user.

Answer (score 0):

Making assumptions about your schema, here is the SQL you can try:

```
SELECT eID , SUM(totalTime) AS sumTotal 
FROM payroll_details 
WHERE payroll_id = ? 
GROUP BY eID 
ORDER BY sumTotal DESC
```